# Android: implementing sliding cards in widget

Tags: android, animation, widget

I have a widget that periodically updates itself (hourly) to display top result of search query. I would like to extend it so it captures several top results and then loops through these. The best example would be `Genie News and Weather` widget for which I was unable to find a source code.

QUESTIONS:

1. What would be a good way to implement the animation? I'm thinking `ViewAnimator` + timer, but is there maybe a better way, say `FrameLayout` + alerts? I'm already using `AlertManager` to periodically pull search results for the widget
2. How bad such arraignment would affect phone's battery life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot animate an app widget by any conventional means. Anything that appears animated is either:

1. Part of the actual home screen application, so there is no inter-process communication and therefore involves much less overhead
2. Eating batteries for lunch, by posting new `RemoteViews` for the app widget every second or so

Comment: There's got to be another way as the "genie" News & Weather Google widget (mentioned in question) updates with news headlines every few seconds, and the battery life is NOT affected from what testing I've done. I'm wondering if it'd be possible to use an AnimationDrawable to display an animated GIF in an ImageView. If so, you could render the text results as an animated GIF then display it that way. Another possible method I've found that may or may not work is using a marquee TextView and programmatically focus/blur to cause the text to scroll and pause appropriately. The Genie gives me hope!